# solve: $(x+1)(yy'-1)=y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

solve: $(x+1)(yy'-1)=y^2$

supposedly it's a a regular Bernoulli equation.
the problem which I face is that I find no reasonable subsition of y'/y. it should be ln, but then I get an e^x, which then seems really complex.

Comment: It's a linear first order differential equation if you substitute $v=y^2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$(x+1)(yy'-1)=y^2$$
$$(x+1)\left(\frac 12 (y^2)'-1 \right)=y^2$$
Substitute $v=y^2$
$$(x+1)\left(\frac 12 v'-1 \right)=v$$

Comment: I stuck with the same expression $(0.5\frac{v'}{v}-\frac{1}{v})=\frac{1}{x+1}$

Comment: do you have a suggestion how to solve it?

Comment: Do you know integrating factor method @peru ?

Comment: This DE can be rewritten as  $$v'-\dfrac {2v}{x+1}=2$$ Then find calculate the integrating factor

Comment: The integrating factor for this DE is $ \mu(x)=\dfrac 1 {(x+1)^2}$. Multiply both side by $\mu(x)$  then integrate. @peru

Comment: Actually I do, but the integration factor should be as function of x and not v.@LostInspace

Comment: Did you see my comment with the integrating factor ? @peru It depends only on x as you can see

Comment: I see now, can you explain how you have written the ode?

Comment: The De becomes $( \dfrac {v}{(x+1)^2})'=\dfrac 2 {(x+1)^2}$ then integrate both sides and get $v$  @peru

Comment: thanks! i succeed.

Comment: Good job @peru. Dont forget that $v=y^2$ unsubstitute $v$ in the end.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I see the relationship was there from the start.

Comment: YYYYYYYYes @amWhy ...........

Comment: Tes, or Yes?? ${}{}{}$

Comment: lol @amWhy big YES. lol

Comment: That's what I thought, *::big smile::*